# Dafny: stronger assertion passes while weaker assertion doesn't

Tags: verification, formal-verification, dafny

The first assertion says that all the values in `missing` array are `0`. The other says at least 1 value in `missing` is `0`. If the first assertion is true, the second must also be true.

[image]

If anyone wants the full code, it is given below. It is essentially a program that finds the missing number in the given array.

```
method FindMissing(n: int, a: array<int>) returns (m: int)
    requires 2 <= n <= 2 * 100000
    requires a.Length == n - 1
    requires forall j, k :: 0 <= j < k < a.Length ==> a[j] != a[k]
    requires forall k :: 0 <= k < a.Length ==> 1 <= a[k] <= n
    ensures 1 <= m <= n
    ensures forall k :: 0 <= k < a.Length ==> a[k] != m
{
    var missing := new int[n];
    var i := 0;

    while i < missing.Length
        invariant 0 <= i <= missing.Length
        invariant forall k :: 0 <= k < i ==> missing[k] == 0
    {
        missing[i] := 0;
        i := i + 1;
    }

    assert forall k :: 0 <= k < missing.Length ==> missing[k] == 0;

    assert exists k :: 0 <= k < missing.Length && missing[k] == 0;

    i := 0;
    while i < a.Length
        invariant 0 <= i <= a.Length
        invariant forall k :: 0 <= k < i ==> missing[a[k] - 1] == 1
        invariant forall k :: i <= k < a.Length ==> missing[a[k] - 1] == 0
        invariant exists k :: 0 <= k < missing.Length && missing[k] == 0
    {
        missing[a[i] - 1] := 1;
        i := i + 1;
    }

    assert exists k :: 0 <= k < missing.Length && missing[k] == 0;

    i := 0;
    while i < missing.Length {
        if missing[i] == 0 {
            m := i + 1;
            break;
        }
        i := i + 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To prove an existential, you often have to supply a witness. To do that for the assertion, add another assertion with the witness in front of it. Like this:

```
assert missing[0] == 0;
assert exists k :: 0 <= k < missing.Length && missing[k] == 0;
```

For the existential quantifier in the loop invariant, I suggest you introduce another variable to hold the witness. If that variable is only used in the proof, you can make it a ghost. You code will look something like:

```
ghost var indexOfMissing := 0;
i := 0;
while i < a.Length
    ...
    invariant 0 <= indexOfMissing < missing.Length && missing[indexOfMissing] == 0
```

You'll have to manually update `indexOfMissing` inside the loop to maintain the invariant.

Here is one other point about logic and two points about Dafny:

- You started by saying the `forall` implies the `exists`. This is not true if the range of the quantifiers is empty. Luckily, in your case, do you have `missing.Length != 0`.
- Your first loop initializes the elements of `missing` to `0`. There are two simpler ways to do that in Dafny. One is to use an aggregate statement that performs a bunch of simultaneous assignments:

  ```
  forall i | 0 <= i < missing.Length {
    missing[i] := 0;
  }
  ```

  The other is to give `new` a function that says how to initialize the elements.

  ```
  var missing := new int[n](i => 0);
  ```

  The beauty with both of these is that they are not loops, and that means you don't need to maintain a loop index and write various loop invariants.
- You can also eliminate the final loop if you use an assign-such-that statement:

  ```
  m :| 0 <= m < missing.Length && missing[m] == 0;
  ```